# Jquery sum of attr values for multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this:

```
<a id="3" class="off area" name = "2" href="">Colchester</a>
<a id="1" class="off area" name = "1" href="">Leicester</a>
<a id="2" class="off area" name = "2" href="">London</a>
<a id="4" class="on area" name = "1" href="">Winchester</a>
```

And I need the sum of the NAME attribute, for links that have a class "on". (i.e. only Winchester).

```
$('.area .on').each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    total += parseInt(this.id, 10);
});
```

I can count the ID's, but not the NAME attributes. So

```
total += parseInt(this.id, 10);
```

is working, but this doesn't:

```
total += parseInt(this.attr('name'), 10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
total += parseInt(this.name, 10);
```

Reason being [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is used on the jQuery object, not directly to `this` keyword.

You can make it better by doing this:

```
total += parseInt(this.name, 10) || 0;
```

making sure you always get a numeric value as a sum.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a jQuery method on DOM element (*`this`*)

You need this -

```
total += parseInt(this.name, 10);
```

Or

```
total += parseInt($(this).attr('name'), 10);
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/dtt7u/

Answer (score 1):

Either you do:

```
total += parseInt(this.name, 10);
```

or:

```
total += parseInt($(this).attr('name'), 10);
```

BTW, use `console.log()` over `alert()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
$('.area.on').each(function(index, elem) {
    sum += parseInt($(elem).attr('name'));
});
```

`.area.on` no space